# Confusion with the use of super() in constructor of derived class in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning classes in JS. Also, I found out that in derived class we must use super() which invokes the constructor of parent class. The question is Why do we need to use super() in the constructor of derived class so as to call THE CONSTRUCTOR OF PARENT CLASS. Why should we care about THE CONSTRUCTOR OF PARENT CLASS. Here is the example:

```
class Car{
constructor(speed)
{
this.speed=speed
}

}

class BMW extends Car
{
constructor(speed)
{
super(speed);
}
}
```

Even if we do not want to use "speed" in derived class we anyways need to use super in derived class

Comment: You don’t need to. `class BMW extends Car {}` inherits the constructor.

Comment: @Ry-, thank you for your kind comments, just briefly, as I wrote above, super() calls THE CONSTRUCTOR OF PARENT CLASS. Just why should we care about the constructor of parent class. Why is the constructor of parent class needed in derived class?

Comment: All-caps don’t make the question you’re asking clearer. Are you wanting to know why it’s necessary for the parent class’s initialization to run at all? Like, philosophically?

Comment: `Even if we do not want to use "speed" in derived class` Why are you extending it if you don't want the functionality it provides?

Comment: @NicholasTower, :) it was just example

Comment: Of course it's an example. I'm just trying to figure out whether the answer to your  question is a variant of "inheriting from the parent is the point of extending a class, and super is part of how that's done" or "classes are the wrong tool for what you're trying to do". So, is it important to you to have the child class gain the behaviors of its parent class?

Comment: @NicholasTower, all I want to understand is why we need to use super() in the constructor of derived class.

Comment: To run the code in that parent constructor, and thus to do all the setup logic defined in that parent constructor.

Comment: @NicholasTower, ok, say, we want to use variables from the constructor of parent class in derived class. As far as I understood, there are two reasons: first, to have possibility to use variables from parent class. Second, to initialize parent class to have possibility to use methods from parent class in derived class. Are both reasons correct?

Comment: @NicholasTower, please I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call super without parameter if you don't need them:

```
class BMW extends Car
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
  }
}
```

> all I want to understand is why we need to use super() in the constructor of derived class.

If you don't use, then it'll create its own constructor rather than parent class constructor inheritance. That is, you will be avoiding to duplicating constructor part when using super.

BTW, in ES7, even if you don't use constructor, it will inherit from parent class.

Comment: This doesn’t seem very meaningful, though.

Comment: @Bhojendra Rauniyar ok, say, we want to use variables from the constructor of parent class in derived class. As far as I understood, there are two reasons: first, to have possibility to use variables from parent class. Second, to initialize parent class to have possibility to use methods from parent class in derived class. Are both reasons correct?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, thank you Bhojendra for your kind comments, my last question is, for example, in React, component extends from React.Component and use, say, componentDidMount which is inherited from React.Component. So, why don't we use super.ComponentDidMount() but use only ComponentDidMount() without using super in front of it? I really need you help

Comment: componentDidMount is not a class but it's method of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a constructor in the child class if you don't have any initialization work to do. In this case the construction in automatically inherited from the parent class (the closest parent that has a constructor).
However, when you are defining a constructor in the child class you need to call `super()` to initialize the object. The `this` property is not available before calling this function as the object wasn't created just yet.